# When i try to give 3 inputs to my program , it needs 4 to run properly. Why is that?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define f(x) (1 / (x*x+1))



int main(){
    double a,b,h,x,y;

    printf("Enter a, b, h:  ");
    scanf(" %lf %lf %lf " , &a, &b, &h);

// I ask for 3 inputs but the programm needs 4 to run...why is that?


    x = a;

     while(x<b)
     {

        y = f(x);
        printf("%lf %lf \n", x ,y );
        x +=h;

     }


    system("Pause");
    return(0);  

}
```

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: @EdChum In the title.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I prefer the question to be in the body personally

Comment: @EdChum That's sexist!

Comment: That code is as far from C++ as it gets.

Comment: [Seems to work okay](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/996afb3df1d9c2b6). Did you not hit <ENTER> to submit the input from your terminal? Please provide more information on how to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's completely valid C++.

Comment: @Scheff You are right sir! The extra spaces was the bug. Thank you very much

Comment: ` f(x) (1 / (x*x+1))` as a macro? Seriously. A fairy is going to die. Plus it's pathological for integral `x`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with your scanf:

```
scanf(" %lf %lf %lf " , &a, &b, &h);
                   ^
```

`scanf` need to see the next non-whitespace to determine the end of this "0 or more whitespaces", so you'll have to give the 4th value (it can be garbage - as long as it's not whitespace) for `scanf` to terminate the input.

If you're on Windows, you can hit Ctrl-Z on a new line and press Enter. This will send an EOF to the program, which can also terminate the input. (I suppose you're on Windows because I see `system("pause")` in your program)

Comment: Yeah, that would be it. Good rule of thumb is to consume leading whitespaces, not trailing ones.

Comment: @CorrurtedDisciple You can click the grey tick beside this answer to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: To avoid appearing OS-ist, you could mention that on UNIX systems ctrl-D sends an EOF to the program.